# How to have Cognito send a verification email for each sign up?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I'm working using AWS's CDK to set everything up but I am manually going thru the login + verification flow using Cognito.

When I create an account for the first time, I get a verification email and when I go back to the page to get verified, it all works.
However, when I go to Cognito's user pool and delete that user/email so that I can test signing up again, I do not get another verification email (with a required code) and I cannot test the verification flow again using the same email as the first time. I am not using SES, am using the default Verification Message email template.

Is there a "reset" of some kind in Cognito that will send me new confirmation emails each time even with the same email?

(I am not getting anything in my junk/spam folder)